# One instance of ResourceBundle to get string resources

Tags: java

I need some help in data resources organization. I have some resource.properties files(LabelResources.properties, ParagraphResources.properties). I can get data from them by the following standard way:

```
private static ResourceBundle myBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.helmes.rentalstore.res.Resource");
myBundle.getString("welcome")
```

I don't like here that moment I need initialize everytime in all classes where I need get a string from recources.Is it possible to do so I can just write the following thing without explicit ResourceBundle initialization:

```
Resources.getBundle("com.helmes.rentalstore.res.Resource").getString("welcome")
```

**UPDATE**

I did it the next way:

```
public enum ResourceBundleType {
    LABELS(ResourceBundle.getBundle("Labels", Locale.ENGLISH)),
    ERRORS(ResourceBundle.getBundle("Errors", Locale.ENGLISH));

    private final ResourceBundle bundle;

    private ResourceBundleType(ResourceBundle bundle) {
        this.bundle = bundle;
    }

    public ResourceBundle getBundle() {
        return bundle;
    }
}


public class Resource {

    private static Resource instance;
    private ResourceBundle bundle;

    private Resource(ResourceBundle bundle) {
        this.bundle = bundle;
    }

    public static synchronized Resource getInstance(ResourceBundle bundle) {

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Resource(bundle);
        } else if (!instance.bundle.getBaseBundleName().equals(bundle.getBaseBundleName())) {
            instance = new Resource(bundle);
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public String getString(String key) {
        if (bundle.containsKey(key))
            return this.bundle.getString(key);

        return null;
    }

    public String getString(String key, Object... params) {
        if (bundle.containsKey(key))
            return MessageFormat.format(this.bundle.getString(key), params);

        return null;
    }
}
```

To invoke it:

```
Resource.getInstance(ResourceBundleType.LABELS.getBundle()).getString("welcome", 1);
```

It`s working right now in my project.
Could you review it? Is it implemented normally by OOP principles and design?

Comment: If your data set is not big enough, you can use common `ResourceBundle`. Something like `public class StringData {private static ResourceBundle strings = ...; public void getString() {return strings.getString(...);}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a wrapper singleton class that does actual bundle initialization once, and just use these bundles on further requests:

```
public class PropertiesHolder {

    private static PropertiesHolder instance;

    private PropertiesHolder() {
        //initialize bundles here
    }

    public static synchronized PropertiesHolder getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new PropertiesHolder();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public String getProperty(String key) {
        //something like return bundle.getstring(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One pattern is to have a centralized `Resources` class for all resource bundles:

```
public class Resources {
    public static final ResourceBundle Labels = ResourceBundle.getBundle("...");
    public static final ResourceBundle Paragraphs = ResourceBundle.getBundle("...");
    // ... more ...
}
```

Usage:

```
label.setText(Resources.Labels.getString("welcome"));
```

But usually you'll group your UI code into java packages and so you might have a resource bundle per (UI) package. In that case, you should write one `Messages` class per java package (that contains a resource bundle):

```
public class Messages {
    private static final ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("...");

    public static String getString(String key) {
        return bundle.getString(key);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
label.setText(Messages.getString("welcome));
```

The Eclipse IDE for example can automatically create such `Messages` classes for you and [helps you to externalize your strings](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-206.htm).

Comment: Interesting suggestions but If I would like to pass some parameters with this string it will be unpossible to use first way. Due to there is hard-coded different kind of bundles and Resources class doesn't understand what bundle I want to use to get a string. Yes, I can use the second way but it looks too much almost the same Messages classes in each UI Java package. May be, there is more elegant way to use global resources with passing parameters inside them?

Comment: @user1376885 So you want to choose the resource bundle based on some (non-constant) parameters? Concerning the Messages-per-package strategie: This is usually used when you have features organized in packages, each feature having its own externalized set of strings.